# How to statically link the library for using SHGetSpecialFolderPath using cl.exe

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` function of the WINAPI, and also using the windows VisualExpressC++ compiler (cl.exe) to compile it. But when in linking stage I get this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___SHGetSpecialFolderPathA@16 referenced in function _main
```

I guess that I need to link `Shell32.lib`, is this correct and how would I do it in a way that I can actually get my program running on another system, maybe even a XP instead of a 7, without recompiling it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're compiling from the command line, just add `shell32.lib` to the command, something like this:

```
cl file1.cpp file2.cpp shell32.lib
```

You're just using a function that Windows provides. Since this particular function goes back almost to the dawn of time (Windows 95, if I recall correctly), you shouldn't have to do anything special to use it on anything reasonably current.

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath was added in IE4, SHGetSpecialFolderLocation works on Win95 RTM or you can use shfolder::SHGetFolderPath (redist). IIRC SHGetFolderPath or something similar also exists by ordinal only in shell32 on old systems...

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will have to link to Shell32.lib. Your program will be compatible to both Windows XP and Windows 7 if you do so (as long as you don't use functions that are only available on Windows 7 or Windows Vista).

You will have to change your command line of cl.exe to:

```
cl program.cpp shell32.lib
```